# maven dependency error

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a project which contains the following pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        cxf-java2ws-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.4.1-fuse-00-43,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>java2ws</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

But I get the following error, which I don't understand:

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:2.4.3-fuse-01-02 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:jar:2.4.3-fuse-01-02: Could not find artifact org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:pom:2.4.3-fuse-01-02 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Can you please help me to understand how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

From the error, we can see that a dependency could not be resolved.

There must be something wrong with one of your dependencies' configuration.

For the first dependency write this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
<version>2.7.0</version>
```

And for the second one write this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
<version>2.7.0</version>
```

---

P.S: You can always check a specific library's configuration using [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse).

Comment: I changed the versions as you said and I run a clean install with the -U option, but I still get the following error: [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:2.4.3-fuse-01-02 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:jar:2.4.3-fuse-01-02: Could not find artifact org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:pom:2.4.3-fuse-01-02 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Is your server connected to internet?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the org.apache.cfx group from your local repository. If that does not help, run maven with -X switch. Open the url of the artifact in a browser and verify that the file is present at the repository and that its pom.xml is valid.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue , when i did a build path to my project for one of the jar file and my project already  had the same jar file . when i deleted the external attached jar file from configure build path , libraries. Issue got resolved .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbgqV.png)